# How to open popup while element drag over the other div?

Tags: javascript, html, css, typescript

I have this piece of code for making draggable Element.
Here I have two divs with different Id . I am looking for some way that while dragging the div (with Id myDiv) over div2 a popup/alert should come and if I take the draggable(i.e myDiv) item outside that div2 it should be removed.

One way to achieve that I can write code inside elementDrag , but if I do this way it will be a bit of tightly coupled . So is there any other way to achieve this (maybe by adding some event listener on the second div).

```js
//Make the DIV element draggagle:
dragElement(document.getElementById("mydiv"));

function dragElement(elmnt) {
  var pos1 = 0,
    pos2 = 0,
    pos3 = 0,
    pos4 = 0;
  if (document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header")) {
    /* if present, the header is where you move the DIV from:*/
    document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header").onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
  } else {
    /* otherwise, move the DIV from anywhere inside the DIV:*/
    elmnt.onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
  }

  function dragMouseDown(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // get the mouse cursor position at startup:
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    document.onmouseup = closeDragElement;
    // call a function whenever the cursor moves:
    document.onmousemove = elementDrag;
  }

  function elementDrag(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // calculate the new cursor position:
    pos1 = pos3 - e.clientX;
    pos2 = pos4 - e.clientY;
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    // set the element's new position:
    elmnt.style.top = (elmnt.offsetTop - pos2) + "px";
    elmnt.style.left = (elmnt.offsetLeft - pos1) + "px";
  }

  function closeDragElement() {
    /* stop moving when mouse button is released:*/
    document.onmouseup = null;
    document.onmousemove = null;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
  #mydiv {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 9;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
  }
  
  #mydivheader {
    padding: 10px;
    cursor: move;
    z-index: 10;
    background-color: #2196F3;
    color: #fff;
  }
  
  #div2 {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: black;
    margin-left: 250px;
  }
</style>

<body>

  <h1>Draggable DIV Element</h1>

  <p>Click and hold the mouse button down while moving the DIV element</p>

  <div id="mydiv">
    <div id="mydivheader">Click here to move</div>
    <p>Move</p>
    <p>this</p>
    <p>DIV</p>
  </div>

  <div id="div2">

  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Thanks

Comment: Instead of implementing the drag-mechanism yourself using `onmousedown`, `onomouseup`, and `onmousemove`, you might look into the [HTML Drag and Drop API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API) where you can have event-listeners for your drag-source and drag-target

Answer (score 0):

```js
//Make the DIV element draggagle:
dragElement(document.getElementById("mydiv"));

function dragElement(elmnt) {
  var pos1 = 0,
    pos2 = 0,
    pos3 = 0,
    pos4 = 0;
  if (document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header")) {
    /* if present, the header is where you move the DIV from:*/
    document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header").onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
  } else {
    /* otherwise, move the DIV from anywhere inside the DIV:*/
    elmnt.onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
  }

  function dragMouseDown(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // get the mouse cursor position at startup:
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    document.onmouseup = closeDragElement;
    // call a function whenever the cursor moves:
    document.onmousemove = elementDrag;
  }

  function elementDrag(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // calculate the new cursor position:
    pos1 = pos3 - e.clientX;
    pos2 = pos4 - e.clientY;
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    // set the element's new position:
    let top = elmnt.offsetTop - pos2
    let left = elmnt.offsetLeft - pos1
    elmnt.style.top = top + "px";
    elmnt.style.left = left + "px";

    let {
      offsetTop: targetTop,
      offsetLeft: targetLeft,
      offsetWidth: targetWidth,
      offsetHeight: targetHeight
    } = document.getElementById("div2");
    if (top > targetTop && top < targetTop + targetHeight && left > targetLeft && left < targetLeft + targetWidth) {
      elmnt.classList.add("over");
    } else {
      elmnt.classList.remove("over");
    }

  }

  function closeDragElement() {
    /* stop moving when mouse button is released:*/
    document.onmouseup = null;
    document.onmousemove = null;
  }
}
```

```css
#mydiv {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
}

#mydivheader {
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: move;
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  color: #fff;
}

#div2 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: black;
  margin-left: 250px;
}

#mydiv.over ~ .popover {
  display: unset;
}

.popover {
  display: none;
  color: white;
  background-color: gray;
  position: absolute;
  left: 300px;
  top: 125px
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <h1>Draggable DIV Element</h1>

  <p>Click and hold the mouse button down while moving the DIV element</p>

  <div id="mydiv">
    <div id="mydivheader">Click here to move</div>
    <p>Move</p>
    <p>this</p>
    <p>DIV</p>
  </div>

  <div id="div2">

  </div>
  
  <div class="popover">
  I'm a popover!
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

This uses CSS to display/hide the popover depending on whether #mydiv has the .over class. The .over class is present when #mydiv is over the target. It is removed when it is not.